# Sublime Text 3 is it possible to change color of react Components in jsx render?

Tags: sublime-text-3, visual-studio-code

I would like to diffrentiate colors of normal html component's tags and react Component's tags. Similar like it is in Visual Studio Code here are two pictures for reference - what i currently have and what i want to achieve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVmax.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colors depend on the syntax package installed. For example, the default JavaScript and the third-party [Babel](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Babel) packages don't color the syntax as you desire, while the [Ecmascript Syntax](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Ecmascript%20Syntax) package does. However, personally I prefer the [TypeScript](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TypeScript) package's highlighting, even for JavaScript.

Comment: Ok after i downloaded it i had to go to View->Syntax->Open all with current extension as -> (chose one of the packages i donwloaded).